# Xcode Storyboard UI Hooked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm my current storyboard I have copied some view controllers from one of my previous projects and once I pasted it in this new project, it is hooked up to my previous project. I have try to remove the reference but it would only remove it from my new project

[image: linked]

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad  : If you seen something wrong then just edit it. don't put other comments.

Comment: yes...this happens with me too....i just restart the xcode and it fixed..